# python setup on windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed python 3.5 on my Windows 7 box. Do I really need to setup environment variables such as

- List item
- PYTHONPATH
- PYTHONSTARTUP
- PYTHONCASEOK
- PYTHONHOME

The installation root folder is C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 and I have added it to path variable.

If yes where should they point to?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  add to path in System PropertiesC:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 
  and  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\scripts and that's all
```

Comment: Thanks much, LetzerWille.